# Visual Studio setup project - windows installer keeps popping up

Tags: windows-installer, installation

I created a Setup project with Visual Studio 2017. Configured it to create a shortcut on the desktop for the primary output of the installed project.

After installation, when I click the icon, windows installer always starts instead of the application. The application works correctly otherwise.

No idea what's wrong or how to troubleshoot this kind of issue. Has anyone ever came across the same ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, turn on [Windows Installer logging policy](https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912407-Create-a-log-file-) (see 2.) so that a log file is always created in your temp folder.

Second, look in the Event Viewer for events from the Windows Installer. If you do this right after launching your Shortcut, you should see messages telling you why the MSI was repaired. The messages will use the Component's GUID, so cross-reference that GUID with your .wxs (or open you MSI in Orca).

Finally, use the log file from the first step to look for references to the Component and see why the Windows Installer thinks the Component is perpetually broken. There are many ways you can cause this problem so hopefully the above helps you track down which one applies to you.

Comment: Thank you, I also found these steps and managed to identify the problem. The root cause was the installer removed some temporary archives used only for installation. As a workaround, I had to move these ZIP archives to resources in the installer class library.